# Cygwin not detecting compiler

Tags: c++, c, g++, cygwin

I've added `C:\cygwin\bin` to my windows path, yet it's still not detecting g++ or gcc when I try to compile from source.

Is there anything I'm missing here? Just installed Cygwin 1.7

Comment: where are you trying to compile, from cygwin shell or windows cmd shell?

Comment: "it's still not detecting g++ or gcc". What isn't detecting g++ or gcc? What command did you issue? What was the precise response or error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cygwin would create a shortcut in start menu called `Cygwin Bash Shell`. You don't have to set `PATH` if you use this.

Compilation tools like `gcc` and `g++` is not installed by default, are you sure you've installed all of them?

btw: I also installed the `ssh` tool of `Cygwin`, which enables me to connect to `Cygwin` using other terminals like `putty`.

Comment: you shouldn't need to use their shortcut as long as you have your path setup right.  most likely the OP didn't install gcc.

Comment: @Nerdtron Thank you. I never used cygwin utilities in normal `cmd` windows.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the alternatives system that's used for switching between gcc versions 3 and 4, `gcc` and `g++` are symlinks to `gcc-3`/`g++-3` or `gcc-4`/`g++-4`. Cygwin symlinks aren't transparent to non-Cygwin programs though, hence you need to invoke the version you want directly.